# How to take the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}2\cos^2(nx)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I wish to take this limit, but I don't know how to approach it. I am not very used to taking limit of a formula in which there are one index and one variable. A limit with just variable $x$ is more familiar to me.

Thank you!

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2\cos^2(nx)$$

Comment: Unless $x=0$, don't see how this will converge.

Comment: I think its unless x is zero or $2k\pi$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How do you evaluate this limit, however. The limit of an expression containing only $x$ is rather intuitive, but if it is a function sequence, it is much harder to evaluate.

Comment: Does not exist except when $x$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: How do you show that it doesn't exist, formally, like calculating.

Comment: Yeah so I would just observe the cases where x is $2k\pi$ and not, separately, prove it doesn't exist in the latter case, it is trivially 2 in the former.

Comment: Cosine is periodic  where $\quad -1 \le \cos(\theta) \le 1\quad$ so you have  limit(s) of $2(\pm1)^2=2$.

Comment: $k\pi$ should be the former case since its squared, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Does not exist using the limit in terms of sequences (Heine)

$$ a_k =  \frac{2\pi \left [ k \right ]}{n} ~~~ \lim a_k = \infty \\ f(a_k) = 2 \cos(\frac{2 \pi \left [ k \right ]}{n} \cdot n)^2 = 2\cos(2 \pi \left [ k \right ])^2 \equiv 2$$

Choosing:
$$ a_k =  \frac{\pi}{2n} + \frac{nk}{n} ~~~ \lim a_k = \infty \\ f(a_k) = 2 \cos( (\frac{\pi}{2n} + \frac{nk}{n})n)^2 = 2 \cos( \frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi)^2 \equiv 0$$

We have two different limits thus the limit does not exist.